# Finding intersections between 2 lists of lists with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 lists of lists.

Case 1

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
y = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I tried numpy.intersect1d

```
import numpy as np
np.intersect1d(x,y, return_indices=True)
>>> (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Desired result

```
>>> (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
```

Case 2

```
x = [[1,2],[3,10],[5,6]]
y = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Desired result

```
>>> (array([1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
```

For me the most important part is know which indices from list x has a **partial**  match in list y. Something similar to:

```
[[0,1], # indices of x
[0,1]] # indices of y
```

Update 1: Using numpy isn't necessary but I need a solution that's fast.
Update 2: fixed the typo in the version on the numpy output

Answer (score 2):

First of all I converted the arrays into numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
y = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

After that, I found their intersections:

```
intersection=np.intersect1d(x,y, return_indices=True)[0]
```

Defined a simple function to compare to lists(I know there's a room for improvement here):

```
def compare_list(list_1, list_2):
for item in list_1:
    if item in list_2:
        return True
return False
```

Finally found what you were looking for(same goes for y):

```
x_finds=[i for i in range(len(x)) if compare_list(x[i], intersection)]
```